# How to write a correct setter method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

There's a setter method in Employee class

```
-(void)setAge:(int)age{
    self.age = age;
}
```

I know that I should use _age instead of self.age. Is there any other problems in this setter method?

I guess maybe I should check the age because if age < 0 is not correct for Employee

Comment: Why? Have you fixed the thing you know is wrong and you still have problems?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD there is not object in the example, `ARC` only work with object since you do not have to retain primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

This is infinite recursive loops. Because it calls again and again...like this...

```
[self setAge:age];
```

So you should do like that..

```
@synthesize age = _age;

- (void)setAge:(int)age 
{
    _age = age;
}
```

Comment: `int *` would seem to be wrong, and you edited like 6 times already?

Comment: With `LLVM` there is also no need to `synthesize` properties, the compiler will do this for you. It will also create the `_age` variable for you.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary, I was just adding to your question, if you do not use the latest version of `LLVM` you might still need to add the `synthesize`

Comment: @rckoenes is it required in latest LLVM. ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary no, it is not. But does save a lot of code :D

Answer (score 0):

This will create infinite loop.

Add in your header file.

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSInteger age;
```

You don't need to use @synthetize in new versions of the xcode.

After you can use the property:

```
 self.age = 15;
 or
 [self setAge:15]
 NSLog(@"Age is %d", self.age);
```

And you can also modify the setter

```
 -(void)setAge:(NSInteger)age {
    _age = age;
    // your code
 }
```